# fixing critical issues after npm audit

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I am trying to fix some issues prompted by npm audit command.
The project has just been upgraded to angular 15.

According to npm audit:
"hermes-engine  <=0.9.0
Severity: critical.
Access of Resource Using Incompatible Type in Hermes - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7mhc-prgv-r3q4.
fix available via `npm audit fix`.
node_modules/hermes-engine
react-native  <=0.0.0-ffdfbbec0 || 0.61.0-rc.0 - 0.67.5
Depends on vulnerable versions of hermes-engine
node_modules/react-native"

I should be able to fix one of the critical issues with npm audit fix commmand. But when I do so, it doesn't fix anything and the critical issue remains.
Any idea on how I can fix it?

My package.json file looks like this :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.13",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "luxon": "^1.25.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.13",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
}
```

Now when I look at hermes-engine, it seems to be related to react native.. Why would i have react native dependencies in my package-lock.json and would it be safe to remove them?

Comment: can you post the result of `npm ls hermes-engine` ? (or `yarn why hermes-engine`)

Comment: The result of npm ls hermes-engine : 
aws-amplify@4.3.13 -->  @aws-amplify/analytics@5.1.11 --> @aws-sdk/client-firehose@3.6.1 --> @aws-sdk/middleware-retry@3.6.1 --> react-native-get-random-values@1.7.2 -->  react-native@0.67.2 -->  hermes-engine@0.9.0

Comment: There you go you have it. `aws-amplify` is responsible for pulling `react-native`.

Comment: Asuming that I can remove hermes-e,gine or even the react native related dependencies. 
How would you proceed in order not to break aws-amplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your deps tree,

```
@aws-sdk/middleware-retry@3.6.1 --> react-native-get-random-values@1.7.2 --> react-native@0.67.2 --> hermes-engine@0.9.0
```

`middleware-retry` doesn't pull `react-native-get-random-values` since [3.12.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/v/3.12.0?activeTab=code).

You best solution would be to update `aws-amplify` !